# How to change the web site portrait mode to landscape mode

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile, dom-events

I am trying to change automatically portrait to landscape mode for 768px devices. Is it possible to change the view mode automatically?

```js
window.addEventListener("orientationchange", function() {

  
});
```

Comment: No JS needed, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries

Comment: i am trying webpage auto rotate to landscape mode, is it possible without JS?

Comment: Yes, it's very possible, just follow the link in my previous comment to find out how.